# DigitalOcean: Deploying Dockerized Django/PostgreSQL and pointing to domain

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have been following the [Django for Professionals](https://djangoforprofessionals.com/) book by William Vincent for a little while. After a few weeks, I've successfully completed my first Dockerized Django/Postgres project.

Rather than deploy to Heroku, I'd like to try my hand at a DigitalOcean "one click install" Docker droplet; however, I've been struggling.

**Steps I've taken to deploy:**

1. Created droplet
2. Created SSH key, new user
3. CD'd into a directory to pull my repo

   `$cd home/user/<repo dir>`
4. Pulled my repo

   `$git pull <repo>`
5. Built the Docker machines

   `docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up --build -d`

```
# dockerfile

# pull base image
FROM python:3.7

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# copy project
COPY . /code/
```

```
# docker-compose-prod.yml
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        # command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        command: gunicorn layoffs.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
        environment: 
            - ENVIRONMENT=production
            - SECRET_KEY=mysecretkey
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:11
        env_file:
            - myenv.env
```

Building the Docker containers works, I'm able to do things like create a superuser using `docker-compose exec web python manage.py createsuperuser`, run migrations, and using `docker-compose logs` shows that it's ready to accept connections.

When I do a `docker ps` I'm able to see the two machines running, both the `web` and `db` services.

**Steps I've taken with DNS and Django:**

1. Added DNS `NS` records from DigitalOcean to my domain's DNS records
2. Created firewall rules in droplet allowing HTTP/HTTPS connections in/out
3. Waited 12 hours
4. Checked `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['mydomain.com', 'my.droplet.ip.address']
```

5. Attempted going to `my.droplet.ip.address`, domain, etc. in my browser with no luck

**Here's my production environment variables:**

```
# settings.py

if ENVIRONMENT == 'production':
    SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
    X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY' # clickjacking
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
    SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 3600
    SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
    SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
    SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

I'm hoping the information I've provided helps, I'm curious if I should just deploy straight to Heroku like the book says? Though I'd like to take advantage of the lower costs while also learning a bit more about DigitalOcean if I can.

I appreciate any help or hints in advance!

Comment: Did you try to get mydomain.com:8000? Also check for gunicorn settings: `secure_scheme_headers = {"X-FORWARDED-PROTO": "https"}` and `forwarded_allow_ips = "*"`. Try to run django server first and then tune up gunicorn.

Comment: I checked the `mydomain.com:8000` with no luck. I've also added to the `settings.py` file the two settings in "production" `secure_scheme_headers` and `forwarded_allow_ips` with no luck. I'm going to keep looking into Gunicorn settings -- as I think I may have had a few issues with those. I think, as of now, the DNS records, `Dockerfile`, and `docker-compose-prod.yml` don't *seem* to be the issue. Seems like it may be rooted in the `settings.py`. I really appreciate the hint!! I will keep plugging away. If you have any more ideas, I'm all ears :)

Comment: Try to replace `command: gunicorn layoffs.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000` with `command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and don't demonize docker `-d` to easily look at it's output.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance frost-nzcr4, unfortunately due to the time constraint with my deployment I'll be going with Heroku. I was able to get this deployed in under an hour using their methods. I will revisit DigitalOcean at a later date to deploy a similar stack when I have more time.